# How do I force Visual Studio's F1 Help to use a specific browser?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have multiple installs of Google Chrome on my Windows 7 PC.

In Visual Studio, when I press F1 to bring up VS's Help.  A Chrome browser launches https://docs.microsoft . . . Everything works fine except the Chrome Browser is not the Chrome Browser I need Visual Studio to use.  it's using one of the other installs of Chrome on my PC.

Does anyone know how to force VS 2017 (on a PC with multiple installs of Chrome on it) to use a particular installation from multiple installs of the Chrome browser?

Comment: I say it's not the right (install) of Chrome because none of my Chrome extensions are on Chrome (when Chrome is launched by Visual Studio via the F1 key)

Answer (score 3):

Using regedit I navigated to

**HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML.R7ICX47S2BPWGRUXWTG7VP7B3Y\shell\open\command**

and modified the existing value. . .

"C:\Portables\Port1\PortableApps\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe" -- "%1"

I changed it to this (below). . .

C:\Portables\Port1\PortableApps\GoogleChromePortable\GoogleChromePortable.exe -- "%1"

Now the desired Chrome browser launches, with all of my extensions etc